# How to change fragment in adapter recyclerview clicked?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I want to change fragment while adapter item recyclerciew clicked, i have use fragment transaction but the fragment is not changed.

please share if you have solved problem like this.
thank you

here's my code

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {


    Handler handler = new Handler();
    final Runnable run =  new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
    String urlThumbnails = list_data.get(position).get("Thumbnails");
    if(urlThumbnails != null){
        Glide.with(context)
                .load(urlThumbnails)
                .into(holder.thumbnailImg);
    }

    holder.title.setText(list_data.get(position).get("Title"));
    holder.itemCount.setText(list_data.get(position).get("ItemCount")+" Videos");


        }
    };
    handler.post(run);

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String PlaylistId = list_data.get(position).get("Id");
            switchFragment(PlaylistId);

        }
    });
}
```

Switch Method

```
private void switchFragment(String id){
    playlistFragment = new PlaylistFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("Id",id);
    playlistFragment.setArguments(bundle);
    Log.d("response playlist", id);
    if(context != null){
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = context.getActivity().getFragmentManager();

        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container,playlistFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }


}
```

Comment: You need to make sure weather your code inside of conditional statement is executing or not.

Comment: you are using `Fragment` or `v4.Fragment`?

Comment: @ShubhamVala i use v4.Fragment

Comment: @stevencaesar you can pass interface object to adapter from the fragment/activity and call the listener method in onclick of adapter and implement the listener in a/f then write your own switch fragment logic in your fragment or activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then Change:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = context.getSupportFragmentManager();
```

For backhandle write below condition in `onBackPressed` and methods in that acticity:

```
if (!(findFragment() instanceof PlayListFragment){
    replaceHomeFragment(ListFragment());
} else {
    super.onBackPressed();
}
....
....
public void replaceDetailFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frm_detail, fragment).commit();
}

public Fragment findFragment() {
    return getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
}
```

Comment: Oke, thanks Shubham.
can you help me again with back press in second fragment and back into first fragment.

Comment: add those fragments in backstack